# "No root filesystem is defined". How do I install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I just managed to find a tool [forgot its name] that makes a live copy of linux on my PC. Now of course I am not just going to try it, delete it. I want to install this thing. The tutorials I have seen look like nothing I have. Let me show you what I mean.

[image]

[image]

It's not the normal screen, no "try" or "install options", just read release notes and asking me do I want third party software.

Explain in full detail.

Comment: Make yourself bootable USB flash with `Unetbootin`, then boot from it and install Ubuntu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: I am confused by your question?  are you running a live version of Ubuntu, and you want to install it?  Are you looking to do a dual boot? Can you explain a little better what you want when you are done?

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you from the picture you have posted it means that:

1. you have **3 NTFS** partitions one with **windows 7 installed**
2. other is **free space** where you want to install ubuntu that means you want to dual boot your machine.
3. to dual boot your machine read below links carefully and follow them.

http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html